# Swift [1,2] conforms to AnyObject but [Enum.a, Enum.b] does not

Tags: swift, types, enums

I'm in AppDelegate, trying to pass a reply to a WatchKit Extension Request. I cannot use an array of enums as the value in a Dictionary whose values are typed as AnyObject. Experimenting in a Playground shows this:

```
enum E : Int {
    case a = 0
    case b
}
var x : AnyObject = [0, 1]  // OK
var y : AnyObject = [E.a, E.b] // [E] is not convertible to AnyObject
```

Of course I can work around this by converting my enums to strings or numbers, but why is this a type error in Swift?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`AnyObject` exists for compatibility with Objective-C.  You can only put objects into an `[AnyObject]` array that Objective-C can interpret.  Swift enums are not compatible with Objective-C, so you have to convert them to something that is.

`var x: AnyObject = [0, 1]` works because Swift automatically handles the translation of `Int` into the type `NSNumber` which Objective-C can handle.  Unfortunately, there is no such automatic conversion for Swift enums, so you are left to do something like:

```
var y: AnyObject = [E.a.rawValue, E.b.rawValue]
```

This assumes that your enum has an underlying type that Objective-C can handle, like `String` or `Int`.

Another example of something that doesn't work is an optional.

```
var a: Int? = 17
var b: AnyObject = [a]  // '[Int?]' is not convertible to 'AnyObject'
```

See [Working with Cocoa Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_43) for more information.

Comment: Ah, you know I was confusing AnyObject with Any. Oops!