# Return an enum with associated value where AnyObject is expected

Tags: swift, enums, swift2, reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to use an `enum` with associated values to capture the result of a flow of [Reactive Cocoa 2.5](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ReactiveCocoa/2.5/index.html) `RACSignal` operations. The API specifies that signals contain `AnyObject` values. I get an error that `Cannot convert value of type 'MyEnum' to expected argument type 'AnyObject!'`. Is there any simple way to wrap my enum values in a reference so that this will work?

Comment: Hi acjay, this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778961/swift-1-2-conforms-to-anyobject-but-enum-a-enum-b-does-not suggests using the rawValue from the enum. Is that something that you might be able to do?

Comment: In this case, no, because the `enum` has associated values

Comment: Ah yes, associated types... like you said in your post sorry=p I was just going to suggest the answer below by Scott. You are right you can wrap it in a Class to store it in an AnyObject. Created a playground to test it. Does seem silly but it works. Who knows, maybe someone can come up with a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have to ask if an `enum` is really the best option here. But if it is, can you not just create your own wrapper?

```
enum MyEnum {
    case MyCase(String)
}

class MyEnumWrapper {
    var myEnum: MyEnum

    init(_ myEnum: MyEnum) {
        self.myEnum = myEnum
    }
}

func takeAnyObject(a: AnyObject!) {

    if let myEnumW = a as? MyEnumWrapper {
        print(myEnumW.myEnum)
    }

}

let tmp = MyEnumWrapper(.MyCase("Hello"))
takeAnyObject(tmp)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing at the moment. But it seems pretty silly.

Comment: Agreed. Lots of silliness in working with Cocoa-like APIs from swift like this. The alternatives (like using unsafe pointers to encode and decode, etc) don't look any prettier though.

Comment: It is too bad reactive cocoa doesn't use generics. Could it be extended to return a generic value? Isn't generics in obj c now available.     Regardless when I think about maybe this answer above is the correct answer, because it is the path of least resistance.  Sometimes over complicating solutions for elegance sake results in undue time being spent.   I'm not sure what you are using reactive coacoa for or how heavily integrated with it you are.  But there is a light weight event system called Signals that uses generics   : https://github.com/artman/Signals. Written in swift.

Comment: That's a good thought. If there is a lot of this going on, the wrapper should be around Reactive Cocoa instead of the enums. Either way, if Reactive Cocoa is one of the fundamental building blocks of this codebase, the solution should be designed to RC's API as much as Swift convention. Enums just might not be the right choice here, or at least the translation should go the opposite direction: making RC-compatible reference types easier to work with by mapping to enums in Swift where appropriate. It's mostly semantics, but I find the distinction helps.

Comment: Yeah, the next version of Reactive Cocoa will indeed have a completely new API that does support generics. But it's not out yet, and it'll be a big refactor. Might check out that Signals project though. We don't do anything incredibly sophisticated with our signals, so it might be a pretty good alternative when we have time to refactor.