# How to cast AnyObject to an enum

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code which uses associated objects to add another property to an existing IOS class.

```
var handle: UInt8 = 0

extension CNContact {
    enum Relationship {
        case Friend
        case Work
    }

    var relantionship: Relationship {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &handle) as? Relationship ?? .Friend
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &handle, newValue , objc_AssociationPolicy(rawValue: objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC.rawValue)!)
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error regarding the `newValue` from the setter, because it expects an `AnyObject` and I'm sending it an enum.

I am not sure exactly how can I use a cast in this situation.

Comment: check answer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778961/swift-1-2-conforms-to-anyobject-but-enum-a-enum-b-does-not May be it will be helpful

Comment: Yep, it worked by deriving my enum from Int , cast newValue to int: Int(newValue.rawValue)